# Again "How to get grub2 to remember last choice?"

Tags: grub2

This question was already [asked once](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148662/how-to-get-grub2-to-remember-last-choice) but it hasn't helped me in my trouble.

I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 on my laptop. Usually I use Windows 7 but GRUB always boots Ubuntu by default. My `/ect/default/grub` contains the following lines:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

I *did* run `sudo update-grub` after I changed the values for these variables. Also I made sure that my `grubenv` file existed and had right permissions (with `save_env` GRUB command).

And still... it doesn't work! GRUB alwas intends to load Ubuntu despite I choosed Windows last time.

What else do I lose sight of?

BTW, I don't have neither RAID nor LVM volumes (at least I don't have LVM manager installed).

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I gave the link to the question you have mentioned. And the answer doesn't solve my case. So it's rather an extension of the quetion.

Answer (score 2):

My situation was similar. I had a custom grub entry (using a 40_custom file in `/etc/grub.d`) for a Chromium OS install. I had set `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` and `GRUB_SETDEFAULT=true`, but it never saved the entry. Turned out that I needed to manually put a "savedefault" line into the 40_custom file in order for that entry to save the default. Works like a champ now.

Edit: If you put `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true`, the `savedefault` line will be added automatically when you run `update-grub`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Grub Customizer for the work it's very simple, just check the box to remember last choice, install it with the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: NB. Grub customizer requires a desktop. It will not be suitable for server installs.

Answer (score 1):

Press Alt+F2
type
 `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` press Enter and enter your password.

you will see this line `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`

You can change the default from 0 to any number, corresponding to the entry in the Grub bootup menu (first entry is 0, second is 1, etc.) so if windows 7 is the 4th entry enter the value to 4

Make your changes, press Ctrl-S to save and Ctrl-Q to exit.

**Important**: Open a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T and type `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes you just made.

Comment: But I don't need Windows 7 always to boot. And I will *not* see `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`. As I have said, in my `/etc/default/grub` `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunately it describes the steps I have performed already. Only one thing was new to me - `GRUB_SETDEFAULT=true` didn't work for LVM and RAID `/boot` partition. I checked whether `lvm` manager was installed on my Ubuntu - it wasn't. And also I don't have any RAID volumes on my laptop.

Comment: It is important having /boot lvm based. check out this "[link][^2]".[^2]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/76095/what-is-the-use-of-boot-lvm-based-in-partitioning